# Meteor: Evaluate helpers again after subscription is ready

Tags: meteor, helper

This article (http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) describes that the helpers of a template are evaluated again after a subscription (which was defined in a iron-router waitOn function) is ready / the client-side collection gets a new item.

My question is, how can I get the same behaviour for a subscription that was defined inside the template (i.e. in the created or rendered function)?

Comment: Helpers are always rerun when the collection changes, no matter where you subscribe. Do you have a code example that is not working as you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for this information! I removed the fields in subscribtion which I used in the query on the client... It is working now. Thank you.